# Random sampling in Apache Spark Java

Tags: apache-spark, random, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

We need to perform random sampling in apache spark using java.
Hence we need to pick random number of exact number of records from a dataset.

We are using below code. Sometimes it doesn’t pick exact number of records.

```
sampledDataSet=sampledDataSet.union(specficClassName.orderBy(rand()).limit(500));
```

**Illustration**:

Suppose in a case DataSet  specficClassName has **700** records it picks 650 even though we have mentioned **500** as a limit in the above example.

We are not getting exact **500** records most of the time.

Can you please help us which function to be used in order to get exact number of records.

Comment: Did oyu try the [`Dataset#sample`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#sample-boolean-double-) method

Not sure if it guarantees an exact number of records, though.